# How to use footnotes in markdown inside html?

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll, kramdown, footnotes

I am trying to use footnotes in Markdown, but when I put it inside HTML (`<div>`) the footnotes won't parse.

Here is the minimal example of the code:

```
a[^1]

<div> 
b[^2]
</div>

[^1]: I am a footnote
[^2]: I want to be a footnote too.
```

And it's parsed like this:

[image]

I was wondering what is the best way to use footnotes inside `<div>` blocks.
Thanks for your help in advance !

Edit: I am using Jekyll with kramdown.

Comment: Footnotes [aren't part](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) of [Markdown](https://spec.commonmark.org/current/), though some tools have added them. What is the specific Markdown tool that you are using?

Comment: Hello. I am using jekyll with kramdown

Comment: Ok, thanks to your comment, I was able to find the solution. Thanks a lot!  
The trick was to surround the footnote with <p> with the markdown argument: ```<p markdown="1"> b[^2] </p>```

Comment: Glad you found a solution. That works in _some_ tools, but not all :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to surround the footnote in a `<p>` block with the markdown argument.

```
<div>
<p markdown="1">
b[^2]
</p>
</div>

[^b]: Now I am a footnote too.
```

Thanks, Chris, for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, @grg. I had this challenge with footnotes in an HTML table. In my case, I didn't want a `<p>` tag for styling reasons, so wrapping the text in a `<span markdown='1'>` worked, too.